ClamAV on Ubuntu 24.04: daemon runs but can't access logfile
I installed ClamAV 1.0.5 on Ubuntu 24.04LTS via Synaptic package manager. Synaptic said installation was a success.
I followed the configuration guidelines in https://docs.clamav.net/manual/Usage/Configuration.html and setup freshclams successfully.
I edited /etc/clamav/clam-config and set the following options pertaining to logging:
LogFile /var/log/clamav/clamav.log
LogSyslog false
LogRotate true
LogFacility LOG_LOCAL6
LogClean false
LogVerbose false

Permissions for the log files are:
$ ls -l /var/log/clamav

total 36
-rw-rw---- 1 clamav clamav  6017 Jul 14 09:04 clamav.log
-rw-rw---- 1 clamav clamav 12458 Jul 14 00:00 clamav.log.1
-rw-rw---- 1 clamav adm      955 Jul 14 08:23 freshclam.log
-rw-rw---- 1 clamav clamav  5103 Jul 13 06:12 freshclam.log.1

Next I rebooted and used systemctl to verify that the daemon runs:
$ systemctl list-units --type=service  
clamav-daemon.service  loaded active running Clam AntiVirus userspace

The systemctl start and stop commands start and stop the service as expected.
Next I ran the clamdscan utility to invoke a scan:
$ clamdscan  
/var/log/clamav: File path check failure: Permission denied. ERROR  
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 1
Time: 0.000 sec (0 m 0 s)
Start Date: 2024:07:14 11:35:12
End Date:   2024:07:14 11:35:12

It's obvious from the ls-l command that the service has logged 6017 bytes to clamav.log and has rotated. Why do I get the permission error when I run the clamdscan utility?
I will let the system run 24/7 for a few days and see if it continues to log and rotate. If anybody has any insights or suggestions in the meantime please feel free to post.

@Archisman Panigrahi I get numerous files from

Still, those files, even if they contain Windows virus, will not affect Ubuntu

@Archisman Panigrahi I realize Windows virus will not affect Ubuntu. I am trying to look out for my friends, that's all. Yes I realize looking out for friends is unacceptable behavior in some circles but that's what I do.

Have you tried sudo clamdscan

@Archisman Panigrahi Yes, I have tried sudo clamscan and it gets the same error mentioned above. I have left the daemon running since yesterday and it is logging to clamv.log so it seems maybe the error message is just a glitch. I haven't configured it to actually scan any directories/files yet due to lack of time. I will do so later today. If it scans and reports and can detect a file I know is infected then I would say the error is  itself an error that can be ignored.

I conclude clamd is broken, maybe at the source level or maybe the .deb package builders broke it. Doesn't matter, I'm just glad somebody tried. I could be wrong but I am not going to spend more time investigating it especially since ClamAv is no longer supported.
Fortunately the ClamAV package installs clamscan in addition to clamdscan. Clamdscan is a clamd client whereas clamscan runs independently of clamd. Clamscan does not throw any errors regarding logfile access like clamdscan does and it does everything I need it to do except download virus signature updates. Fortunately the freshclam utility can be easily used to download new signatures and maintain the database. So I will use clamscan and freshclam in a bash script. I won't have On Access Scanning or email scanning but I don't need those features.
